# How to add a geoserver layer to openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I am trying to add a geoserver layer with 2 points on the openlayers. But I only get the map without the points. This is what I try:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>OpenLayers Example</title>
   <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
   <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
     var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');


      var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
      "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'} );


     var cabin= new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "Cabins",
            "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
            {layers: "cite::obj_geom",
                transparent: false,
                TILED: false,
                styles: "point"
            },
    {isBaseLayer: false,
        displayInLayerSwitcher: true,
        format: "image/png",
        visibility: false,
        displayOutsideMaxExtent: false,
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")

    }
  );    

map.addLayers([wms,cabin]);
map.zoomToMaxExtent();
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought it was the projections but I changed it to EPSG:900913, the same with the openlayers map projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me fine:

```
wms_layer_komvoi = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Κόμβοι - WMS","https://www.ruralauditor.gr/geo_wms",  //http://192.168.2.6:8080/geoserver/wms
        {
            layers: 'rural_II:komvoi', //store:layer_name
            transparent: true,
            tiled: true
        },
        {
            format: "image/png",
            //STYLES: "pointOikismoi",
            visibility: false,  
            displayOutsideMaxExtent: false,
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
        }
    );
```